# Having issues with - $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']

Tags: php, include

I know I'm doing something stupid and probably obvious, but I'm not sure what. In my `header.php` I have:

```
define('ABSPATH', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
require_once(ABSPATH . "/config.php");
```

Using this produces the following error:

```
Warning: require_once(localhost/config.php): failed to open stream: 
No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\inc\header.php on line 4 
Call Stack: 0.0002 684176 1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\index.php:0 0.0003 
696152 2. require_once('C:\wamp\www\inc\header.php') C:\wamp\www\index.php:2 
Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'localhost/config.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\inc\header.php on line 4 Call Stack: 
0.0002 684176 1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\index.php:0 0.0003 696152 2. require_once('C:\wamp\www\inc\header.php') C:\wamp\www\index.php:2
```

However, if I navigate directly to `localhost/config.php` (currently, it's just a simple 1 line file that is echoing a sentence) It will work.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` should do the trick

Comment: +1 You are correct, an explanation of why `localhost/config.php` works in his browser but not with require would be nice though. Describing `URL fopen wrappers` and how with them turned on `require("http://" . ABSPATH . "/config.php")` would work, and why that is a bad idea would all be good.

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! @PaulP.R.O. - would you explain why it's a bad idea? What should I be using?

Comment: It's a bad idea to use `require` with `http` because all your requires/includes will be made through http. That's not necessary since your file is on the same server you can just open it. `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will give you the filesystem path to your webroot. From there you can access config.php.

Comment: You could also use `require(__DIR__ . '/../config.php')`

Answer (score 2):

`include`s and anything else that works with *files as seen from the server* work with *file system paths*. `C:\foo\bar` is a file system path. `localhost` is not, `localhost` is the hostname of a URL as seen from the network. The file `localhost/config.php` is valid when treated as a URL over a network. The same file on the local system has a path like `C:\wamp\www\config.php`, which is what you need to use to `require_once` it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you didn't mean to use a backslash on your Windows system, there?

Also, make sure the file is in the `localhost` folder *within your web root*.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
define('ABSPATH', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
require_once(ABSPATH . "/config.php");
```